# C#: Glass Forms?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, themes, aero

How can I use aero glass to cover my entire forms? Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MARGINS
{
    public int Left;
    public int Right;
    public int Top;
    public int Bottom;
}

[DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
public static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS pMargins);
```

Then you can enable it on your form like so:

```
MARGINS marg = new MARGINS() { Left = -1, Right = -1, Top = -1, Bottom = -1 };
DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(form.Handle, ref marg);
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. You should fix the struct so it's in code tags.

Comment: Cool. BTW `marg` should be passed to `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` as a `ref` (ie `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(form.Handle, ref marg);`)